# Android AsyncTask Url

Tags: android-asynctask

There is a method protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {}.
what does URL... urls means?

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

These is from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "type ... name" syntax is Java for variable-length argument list. It means zero or more URL values. They are referenced by treating urls (in this case) as an array (URL[] urls) in the method. In the case of AsyncTask, you'd pass one or more URLs in the .execute() method: .execute(url1, url2, url3).